# Call a function when the enter button is pressed via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem, I want to call a function inside a textbox, when I press enter, this is my code

```
<input  type="text" value="DIGITE O LOCAL" onclick="this.select()" size="20" id="endereco">
```

I want to put something like `onenterpress="doSomething()"`

How can I do this ?

Comment: Inline event handlers are the wrong approach. Keep JS in `.js` files.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you want to use obtrusive Javascript:

```
<input type="text" value="DIGITE O LOCAL" onclick="this.select()" 
onKeyDown="if(event.keyCode==13) alert(5);" size="20" id="endereco">
```

Handling this unobtrusively:

```
document.getElementById('endereco').onkeydown = function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        alert('5');
    }
}
```

Your best choice is to use the latter approach. It will aid in maintainability in the long run.

**Reference**: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript

Comment: Simple and worked, thank you =) (I need to wait more 5 minutes do check as "accepted" your answer

Answer (score 4):

**HTML**

```
<input  type="text" value="DIGITE O LOCAL" onkeypress="doSomething(this, event)" onclick="this.select()" size="20" id="endereco">
```

**JS**

```
function doSomething(element, e) {
    var charCode;

    if(e && e.which){
        charCode = e.which;
    }else if(window.event){
        e = window.event;
        charCode = e.keyCode;
    }

    if(charCode == 13) {
        // Do your thing here with element
    }
}
```

Comment: Inline JS event handlers are almost always a bad idea.

Comment: I'm not refactoring the OP's code just answering his question. No need for a downvote.

Answer (score 4):

Daniel Li's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12642602/1258041) is the slickest solution, but you may encounter a problem with IE and event.keyCode returning undefined, as I have in the past. To get around this check for window.event

```
document.getElementById('endereco').onkeydown = function(event){
    var e = event || window.event;
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
        alert('5');
    }
}​
```