# How to call the click JavaScript event when pressing a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to write code in JavaScript or jQuery, so call the click event after pressing the button?

HTML:

```
<form action="#" method="get">

    <button type="submit">Turn to the dark side</button>
</form>
```

Comment: call what event, the submit event in a form or?

Comment: yes, this button is in a form

Comment: it will be called automatically

Comment: halfter, i want to call click

Comment: [Look here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18485054/2569323)

Comment: (When replying to people here, use their handle e.g. `@halfer`. Tab auto-complete is available).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call a function when the enter button is pressed via Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12642571/call-a-function-when-the-enter-button-is-pressed-via-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript you can write the code in following

Turn to the dark side

```
    <script>
     function clickMe(){
     alert("Hello World");
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you need but clicking on the button below fires the alert. Put any function (event) in there.

https://jsfiddle.net/9p70hwyL/

```
<button type="submit" onclick="alert('The event')">Turn to the dark side</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

`<button id="target" onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>`

Or with jquery :

```
$( "#target" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need in JavaScript.

```js
function submitForm(){
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

```css
#bg{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="bg" ></div> 

<form action="#" method="get">
    <button onclick="submitForm()" type="button">Turn to the dark side</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Great, although the function is now misnamed `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, you can write the code in following two ways

```
<button type="submit" click="alert('Hi');">Turn to the dark side</button>
```

**OR**

```
    <button type="submit" click="buttonClicked();">Turn to the dark side</button>
function buttonClicked() {
   alert('Hi');
}
```

In Jquery, you can call event by class name (css class) and id.

```
<button type="submit" id="btn">Turn to the dark side</button>

$("#btn").click({
   alert('Hi');
});
```

OR

```
<button type="submit" class="btnClass">Turn to the dark side</button>

$(".btnClass").click({
   alert('Hi');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Theres the html onClick() method.

For example

```
<button onClick="return sampleFunction()">Click me!!!</button>
```

In JavaScript

```
function sampleFunction()
{ 
    alert("abc"); 
    return false;
}
```

This return `false` will stop the button's default action, for example like form posting. If you return `true`, it'll continue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but it did not help me. Look at this:

```
    <form action="http://youtube.com" method="get">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input id="checkbox_vader" type="checkbox" name="character" value="dark_side">
      <label for="checkbox_vader" data-sentence="There is no escape from the Dark Side.">Vader</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button type="submit">Turn to the dark side</button>
</form>
```

I would like to do `if-else` in javascript/jquery. Please, can u told me, how to start writing code in js / jq?