# How to modify onKeyDown event with Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a project in which a javascript function runs when either 1) a button is clicked or 2) the "return" key is pressed. The javascript function sets a div's visibility to "visible" and changes the "onclick" and "onKeyDown" attributes to run a different function when clicked/pressed a second time.

For example, clicking the button (or pressing return) once will make the div appear, and doing it twice should make it disappear.

The problem is that I cannot figure out how to make the javascript change the "onKeyDown" attribute when the function is triggered. Is this possible?

I based my code off of this answer: [Call a function when the enter button is pressed via Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12642571/call-a-function-when-the-enter-button-is-pressed-via-javascript#answer-12642602)

Here is my code so far:

```js
function visible() {
document.getElementById("box").style.visibility = "visible";
document.getElementById("button").onclick = hidden;
document.body.onKeyDown = "if(event.keyCode==13) hidden()";
}

function hidden() {
   document.getElementById("box").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("button").onclick = visible;
    document.body.onKeyDown = "if(event.keyCode==13) visible()";
}
```

```css
#box {
  visibility:hidden;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:red;
}


#button {
  width:120px;
  height:50px;
  background:lightblue;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body onKeyDown="if(event.keyCode==13) visible()">

<div id="box"></div>
<div id="button" onclick="visible()" ></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Clicking the blue box will make the red box appear, and so will pressing return; but pressing return again will not make the box disappear.

Comment: Pretty well written for a first question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onkeydown` property for JavaScript is case sensitive. Thus, using `onKeyDown` will set a *different* function to `hidden`, while the body's keydown action is still `visible()`.

To fix it, change `onKeyDown` to `onkeydown` in both files. It's kinda confusing at first since it doesn't follow the usual capitalization syntax, but all HTML attributes are lowercase.

Also, set `onkeydown` to a function, rather than a string:

```js
document.body.onkeydown = function(){if (e.keyCode==13) visible()};
```

Lastly, `e` is not defined. Replace it with `event`, and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your code definitely seems to be _changing_ the "onkeydown" attribute; because clicking on the blue button twice and then pressing return does not make the red div appear. But it still isn't actually making the red div disappear. Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uqz1xoya/

Comment: @htmlcat `e is not defined`. Try changing to `event`.

Comment: @htmlcat alternatively you could replace your entire javascript with just 
https://jsfiddle.net/ganeshie8/7t6ry4v1/7/

Comment: @rsadhvika Post that in your answer...it'd make it more original.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function visible() {
  document.getElementById("box").style.visibility = "visible";
  document.getElementById("button").onclick = hidden;
  document.body.onkeydown = function() {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) hidden()
  };
}

function hidden() {
  document.getElementById("box").style.visibility = "hidden";
  document.getElementById("button").onclick = visible;
  document.body.onkeydown = function() {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) visible()
  };
}
```

```css
#box {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}

#button {
  width: 120px;
  height: 50px;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body onKeyDown="if(event.keyCode==13) visible()">

  <div id="box"></div>
  <div id="button" onclick="visible()"></div>

</body>

</html>
```